# Get all selected items in a TreeStore

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a TreeStore that you can drill into.  It's only two levels deep.  When you get to the second level and you click on a leaf it takes you to a detail card.

How do I, in the detail card, show the full path?

So say I have;

```
 - A
 -  1
 -  2
 - B
 -  1
 -  3
 - C
 -  5
 -  2
```

So when I click on B and then 3 I want to have "B" and "3" ideally in a Javascript variable that I can then pass to a WebService.

Comment: Did my answer help you in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe SenchaTouch has no built in functionality for this.
You can listen for the itemtap event and then store the title of your item in an array.
When you show your detailcard you could pass this array to you webservice and show the joined array in your card.

Unfortunately i don't know what your code looks like and if you use the MVC approach but it would probaply something like this:

```
breadcrumbs = []

onItemTap = function( list, target, record ){
   breadcrumbs.push( record.get('title') );
}

onLeafItemTap = function() {
   breadcrumpsStr = breadcrumbs.join('->');
   // send them to your webservice
   // set in your detailCard
   breadcrumps = []
}
```

When you provide your code I could help you more.